# Tangled Mess try catch Block

Tags: java, exception

```
public int countChars3(String fileName) {
        int total = 0;
        FileReader r = null;
        try {
            r = new FileReader(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File named " + fileName + " not found. " + e);
            total = -1;
        }
        try {
            while (r.ready()) {
                try {
                    r.read();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IOException" + "occurred while counting " + "chars. " + e);
                    total = -1;
                }
                total++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOExceptionoccurred while counting chars. " + e);
            total = -1;
        }
        try {
            r.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOExceptionoccurred while counting chars. " + e);
            total = -1;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

The above code is an example of a tangled mess try-catch block. By reading through the code, they do look messy, there are several nested try-catches. In broad strokes, what is this tangled mess code block trying to demonstrate?

Comment: That there are many different ways for file I/O to fail?

Comment: There are several points of failure and their respective handling.

Comment: @YogendraSingh is this an example of what we should not do in programming? or is this something we're likely to see if we want to guard against all those exceptions?

Comment: This almost couldve been valid C# code. Are java and C# that much alike?

Comment: @user133466: It's a very good question. You can do excessive exception handling as in your example. There are two kinds of exceptions. For Runtime Exceptions, you need to think, what is the possibility of occurrence. If it is possible, then exception handling is required. For checked exceptions, you will need the handling. For example, `NullPointerException`. If you think your value will never be null then its fine, but if you think, its possible, then you need to handle it.

Comment: Regardless of the try-catch mess, this code is completely incorrect.  `ready()` can return false while there's still data to come.  The close needs to be in a finally block.  Etc, etc.

Comment: *"In broad strokes, what is this tangled mess code block trying to demonstrate?"* - You would need to ask the author.  What it is actually demonstrating is that the author doesn't really know what they are doing ... if this is real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have the method throw it and let the client deal with it, also you should prob have a finally{} to close the resource.

```
public int countChars3(String fileName) throws IOException {
    int total = 0;
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
    try {
        while (reader.ready()) {
            reader.read();
            total++;
        }
        reader.close();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    return total;
}
```

Also are you meaning to count chars or bytes, if bytes your entire code can be replaced with:

```
return (int) new File(fileName).length();
```

Comment: do you think Jeff's code is correct without putting the `r.close()` in the finally clause?

Comment: I've read it's best practice otherwise your app could leak file pointers if exceptions keep getting raised mid-parse.

Comment: There is no reason to put `reader = new FileReader(fileName)` in the try-finally block. If it fails, there is nothing to close anyway. Putting it in the declaration will remove the need for the if statement in the finally.

Answer (score 1):

It tries to locate and open a file, then it tries to count the characters in that file.  Then, it tries to close the file.

Personally, I would never write this kind of code in production. I would try to do all of this and put it all in one try/catch block, unless there was a lot of processing going on in between, like so:

```
try {
    r = new FileReader(fileName);
    while(r.ready()) {
        r.read();
        total++;
    }
    r.close();
}
catch(IOException ioe) {
    //handle
}
```

Of course, if you want more specificity when you catch the IOException as to what occurred, then you need the separate blocks. It's a tradeoff between readability and functionality

Comment: would you say this is a good practice for writing try-catch if you need to guard against exceptions under those scenarios?

Comment: Personally, I would never write this kind of code in production.  I would try to do all of this and put it all in one try/catch block, unless there was a lot of processing going on in between.  Of course, if you want more specificity when you catch the IOException as to what occurred, then you need the separate blocks.  It's a tradeoff between readability and functionality.

Comment: There are a number of issues with the way the code is written.  The practice of checking for and dealing with exceptions of specific types of interest is fine, however.

Comment: @Jeff can you please show me how you would write the above code in try-catch?

Comment: @Jeff do you think you'd need a finally clause for `reader.close();`?

Answer (score 0):

What does this demonstrate?

I'm going to go with: broken code.

Combining all of these into a single try-catch would not only be more readable, but also more correct.  The main problem is that catching an unrecoverable exception early (such as the FileNotFound) it still continues with the rest of the code (here it will throw unhandled NPEs).

Comment: What does NPE stand for?

Comment: @user1534664 null pointer exception